# Insert empty page between groups when reportviewer renders

Tags: reportviewer

I want exactly what others on help forums don't: I need to put a blank page between reportview grouping data.

I have a database table which returns data grouping them based on a specific column, and this report is rendered to PDF before printing. My company uses a double face printer, so printing uses two sides of an paper sheet, not only for money savings, but because data is related to hospital´s patient records. When I render the PDF, the data is grouped by patient. Everything is working well on rendering and would work well if the records were printed only in one sheet side. But we gotta use 2 sides.

When I print this PDF, some data records of an patient is printed on the same sheet of other patient (ex: an patient needs 5 pages to print his records... the records of next patient will start on page 6, same sheet... thus the records of first patient ends in 3th sheet and, in this sheet, records of second patient starts...) So I need to put a separator (I´ve thought a blank page with every grouping starting on odd) but I can´t figure it out.

Page breaks are set and work well. I need a 'sheet break'... If it was records of 2 or 3 patients, we could do it manually. But with 70, 100 patients this becomes a tough task... We could send records directly to printer, on a loop or something, by patient and without preview, but it would put many objects on print spooler, and whe think this could be a problem, since paper can get stuck our other problems could arrive in this process... So we prefer what we call sheet break.